# Give me such a $"3n±Q"$ problem that we do not know a counter-example

Tags: examples-counterexamples, collatz-conjecture

Maybe, This question is stupid.But, I want to ask.Because, really I dont Know answer.This problem may be similar to others. My Question is:

$$ f(n) =
\begin{cases}
Pn±Q          & \text {if $n$ is odd} \\
\frac{n}{2}   & \text {if $n$ is even} 
\end{cases} ,$$ and we can find such $k$ 
$$f^{k}(n)=1$$ Here $P,Q\in
\mathbb{N}$

> For Example: We know counter examples, for $"3n-5","3n-1",3n+5"$ problems. So that $f^{k}(n)≠1$

Give me such a problem that we do not have a counter-example,(In shortly $f^{k}(n)=1$)

***If the example you give is $"3n ± Q"$, and "$Q≠1"$ it was very good.***

*(Please, edit or improve question for me,because Unfortunately, I'm not as knowledgeable as you.) Thanks so much!*

Comment: I think it's not so interesting. Collatz took already his place with his $3n+1$ conjecture.

Comment: It is not my question. I want to know , is there a problem like a collatz conjecture  ("$3n+K"$) ,which that we dont know counter-examples.$"K≠1"$

Comment: You wrote that “We all know that,There is no counter-examples for Collatz Conjecture”. Actually, if we all knew that, then it wouldn't be a conjecture anymore, right?

Comment: @JoséCarlos Santos Dear teacher, Please edit question for me..I may not have expressed myself well.I am so sorry.

Comment: @Idontknow I would like to help you, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: @JoséCarlos Santos..ı am sorry this situation, I am looking for **"alternative $3n±K$ problem."** and $K≠1$ .(I use google translate..)Which that we dont know counter-examples numbers don't go to $1$.

Comment: @Idontknow Are you looking for a problem similar to the Collatz conjecture for which there are known counter-examples?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos this is a question of English rather than maths, but it depends what you call an "example". An example needs to be demonstrable really in order to be an example so until we find one there is no counterexample to the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: I edited the question..

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I edited my question..Can you look again?

Comment: @Idontknow There are several things that I do not understand, even after your latest edition.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos What are these??

Comment: @Idontknow I am sorry, but I do not have time for this right now.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I wish I could express myself well...I am so sorry...

Comment: Mathew is a researcher of collatz-like conjecture. http://www.numbertheory.org/php/collatz.html

Answer (score 2):

Surely the article *"On the '3x+1'-Problem"* of *R.E.Crandall* of 1978 fits your question well (it is online you can find it). Here is a screenshot of a part of that article dealing with the general $qx+r$-problem-variant:

---

[image: picture]

---

source: MATHEMATICS OF COMPUTATION, VOLUME 32, NUMBER 144, Oct 1978

---

As an interesting sidenote: I've found a second cycle with the $q=181$ - problem. And also the $q=3511$ (having a similar property as $q=1093$ being a wieferich prime) should have been looked at.
But I think there was ***no substantial progress*** over this material of 1978... *(it should then also be mentioned in the wikipedia, btw.)*

Comment: You say that, there are not $P$ and $Q$?? Always $f^{k}(n)=1$?? ($P≠3$ and $Q≠1$)