# Possible variation of the $"3n+1"$ problem as $"3n+K"$

Tags: number-theory, functions, examples-counterexamples, collatz-conjecture

Variations of the [Collatz problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CollatzProblem.html)

---

Let

$$ f(n) =
\begin{cases}
3n+K          & \text {$n$ odd} \\
\frac{n}{2}   & \text {$n$ even} 
\end{cases} $$ with $$K\in\mathbb Z^*$$

I am looking for $K\neq1$ such that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})\,\,\, f^k(n)=1$ for large enough $k$.

Comment: Just checking, but $+1$ is just $1$? I also find your question slightly confusing - I'm failing to interpret '( Variations of the "3n+1""3n+1" problem) "any" ...' and 'I mean from the "any n∈Nn∈N", we don't know counterexample for now, which that'. Could we have a link/explanation to this problem?

Comment: @Shuri all $±K$ variations

Comment: I don't quite understand the emphasis placed on $\pm$ signs here. $K\in\mathbb Z^*$ and $K\neq1$ is what normally would be written.

Comment: @Shuri I am new,İf you understand my question ,can you edit for me?

Comment: If you're really new, you could have a look at this question, and the reasons why it was put on hold: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360315/give-me-such-a-3n%c2%b1q-problem-that-we-do-not-know-a-counter-example?rq=1

Comment: @StrangeUser I've put in an edit as a suggestion. If you don't like it, you can rollback to the edit before.

Comment: @Shuri You are experienced from me, definetly.

Comment: First thing I'd observe is that $K$ must be odd and positive.

Comment: @Shuri Definetly $k$ must be odd number.

Comment: @Shuri maybe we can edit $2K-1$

Comment: if k is a multiple of 3 all odd numbers hit multiples of 3. k=3 would lead to $3 \mapsto 12\mapsto 6\mapsto 3$ for example and k=6 leads to $3\mapsto 15\mapsto 51\ldots$ k=9 leads to $3\mapsto 18 \mapsto 9\mapsto 36\mapsto 18\ldots$ etc.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee You have misunderstood the question.

Comment: I think it's you don't understand the problem. otherwise, you may not have asked the correct question.  I've shown that if K is a multiple of three, so will all the results once it hits an odd number.

Comment: Perhaps you are interested in a short compilation on the $3x+r$-problem. See http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_3x_r.pdf It suggests by heuristics, that the $3x+r$-problem with odd $r>1$ has cycles not including $1$ and tries to explain some pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $K\neq 1$ and it's odd, your sequence will always contain a cycle: $$K, 4K, 2K, K$$

If $K$ is even, one can see the sequence increases infinitely once it hits odd number since it never comes back into even number.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand anything.

Comment: $f(f(f(K)))=f(f(4K))=f(2K)=K$ so the sequence never goes to 1 if it starts at $K$!

Comment: Now I understood...

Comment: Thanks for answer.✓